# jquery menu, hover and display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, drop-down-menu

I have this menu http://jsbin.com/useqa4/3

The hover I think works correct, but what I want is the normal: when the user's cursor isn't on the "Solution" item or on the submenu then I want the div `#submenuSolutions` to return in "display:none".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I really like the styling you have there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [See Demo](http://jsbin.com/useqa4/4)

---

Just added this code to hide it back when mouse leaves it:

```
  $("#submenuSolutions").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
```

Since `submenuSolutions` is the id of your panel, you can use the `mouseleave` event which triggers when mouse leaves the area of element specified.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the jQuery api more carefuly you will see that the hover function can take handle two events http://api.jquery.com/hover/

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("#menuSolutions a").hover(function () {
      $("#menuSolutions").addClass("menuHover");
      $("#submenuSolutions").show("3000");
  },function() {
    $("#menuSolutions").removeClass("menuHover");
    $("#submenuSolutions").hide("3000")});
});​
```

This will work only if your menu is a suckerfish menu.

Comment: That will hide it back when mouse leaves menu item

Comment: Hmm yes you're right. It works only if the #submenuSolutions was a ul inside the #menusolutions li

Comment: @Sotiris if you dont use a suckerfish then use Sarfraz solution